# Change database name of table in workbench EER Diagram

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

I am working on an EER diagram and stuck: by mistake I forgot to change to the correct database, and created all tables within the wrong database.

Can any one help me out from this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to copy the table in the overview page and paste it into the other schema. Then remove it from the first schema.